Is it possible that the number of $\mathcal{T}$-algebras is an arithmetic progression?
For a single-sorted algebraic theory $\mathcal{T}$ denote by $t_n$ the number of $\mathcal{T}$-algebras with $n$ elements (up to isomorphism). Is there an example for $\mathcal{T}$ such that eventually $t_n$ is a non-constant arithmetic progression? By this I mean that there are $N,a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ with $a > 0$ such that $t_n = a \cdot n + b$ for all $n \geq N$. In particular, $t_n$ must be eventually strictly increasing. Is it maybe even possible to have $a=1$?
Some context. The sequence of the numbers of groups of order $n$ (up to isomorphism) is a quite complicated sequence, it is not increasing in particular. The sequence of the numbers of posets of order $n$ (up to isomorphism) is strictly increasing for $n \geq 1$, as can be checked easily by adjoining a smallest element to a given poset. There is also an algebraic theory with this property, namely $\mathbb{Z}$-sets, or equivalently, sets equipped with a bijection. Here $t_n$ is the number of conjugacy classes in $S_n$, which is equal to the number of integer partitions of $n$. This sequence is eventually strictly increasing, but of course not an arithmetic progression. I have excluded constant sequences ($a=0$) since otherwise sets would provide a boring answer.
I believe that such an algebraic theory must be very very nice, hence my curiosity if it exists. Maybe some mathematical logic will be helpful to answer this question.

Is it possible that the number of $\mathcal{T}$-algebras is an arithmetic progression?
Here is a near miss: Let $\mathcal{V}$ be the variety of $\mathbb Z_2$-sets. These may be thought of as algebras $\langle X; \alpha(x)\rangle$ with a single unary operation $\alpha(x)$ such that $\alpha^2(x)=x$. The number of isomorphism types of algebras of size $n$ in this variety is $t_n=\big\lfloor\frac{1}{2} n\big\rfloor+1$.

Edit. I will leave the original answer above, but edit it to make it more complete.
This will be an example of a variety of algebras in which there are exactly $n$ isomorphism types of algebras of size $n$ for each $n$. The language is the language of one unary operation $\alpha(x)$ and one constant $c$. We axiomatize the variety with the single axiom $\alpha^2(x)=x$. Each algebra in the variety is a disjoint union of $1$-element orbits under $\alpha$ and $2$-element orbits under $\alpha$, and one of the orbits is distinguished by the fact that one of its elements is named $c$.
In the original answer, the constant was missing. To count the number of isomorphism types of structures of this type which have size $n$ it suffices to specify the number of $2$-element orbits in a model. This can be any number $k$ chosen from $k=0,1,\ldots,\lfloor \frac{1}{2}n\rfloor$, so there are $\lfloor \frac{1}{2}n\rfloor+1$ possible isomorphism types of constant-free structures of size $n$.
James Hanson suggested adding the constant $c$. This distinguishes one of the orbits, say $O_c$. If $O_c$ is a $1$-element orbit, then the isomorphism type of the model is determined by the isomorphism type of the remaining constant-free structure of size $n-1$, so there will be $\lfloor \frac{1}{2}(n-1)\rfloor+1$ of these algebras. If $O_c$ is a $2$-element orbit, then the isomorphism type of the model is determined by the isomorphism type of the remaining constant-free structure of size $n-2$, so there will be $\lfloor \frac{1}{2}(n-2)\rfloor+1$ of these algebras. Altogether, this yields $\lfloor \frac{1}{2}(n-1)\rfloor+1+\lfloor \frac{1}{2}(n-2)\rfloor+1 = n$ isomorphism types.

A small modification of this example works. If you add a constant $c$, then the number of isomorphism types is $\lfloor \frac{1}{2}(n-1)\rfloor + 1 + \lfloor \frac{1}{2}(n-2)\rfloor +1 = n$.

@JamesEHanson: Excellent!

Thanks a lot! Can we add this to the answer, or have a separate answer by James, for better visibility of the final example?

Does the constant need to satisfy any axiom?

@MartinBrandenburg No the constant does not need to satisfy any axiom.
